# Why? My stupid discord bot code is not working

Tags: python, pycharm

```
 @bot.command()
 async def 재생(ctx, *, msg):
     if not vc.is_playing():
         global entireText
         YDL_OPTIONS = {'format': 'bestaudio', 'noplaylist': 'True'}
         FFMPEG_OPTIONS = {'before_options': '-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5',
                           'options': '-vn'}
 
         chromedriver_dir = "D:\프로잭트더벽람Uselles봇\comedriver"
         driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_dir)
         driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=" + msg + "+lyrics")
         source = driver.page_source
         bs = bs4.BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
         entire = bs.find_all('a', {'id': 'video-title'})
         entireNum = entire[0]
         entireText = entireNum.text.strip()
         musicurl = entireNum.get('href')
         url = 'https://www.youtube.com' + musicurl
 
         with YoutubeDL(YDL_OPTIONS) as ydl:
             info = ydl.extract_info(url, download=False)
         URL = info['formats'][0]['url']
         await ctx.send(
             embed=discord.Embed(title="노래 재생", description="현재 " + entireText + "을(를) 재생하고 있습니다.", color=0x00ff00))
         vc.play(FFmpegPCMAudio(URL, **FFMPEG_OPTIONS))
     else:
         await ctx.send("이미 노래가 재생 중이라 노래를 재생할 수 없어요!")
```

this is my code but this dam thing is tell me

```
     C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/A~Z azur lane project/music.py:67: DeprecationWarning: executable_path has been deprecated, please pass
 in a Service object
       driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_dir)
     Ignoring exception in command 재생:
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "D:\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76,
 in start
         creationflags=self.creationflags)
       File "D:\lib\subprocess.py", line 775, in __init__
         restore_signals, start_new_session)
       File "D:\lib\subprocess.py", line 1178, in _execute_child
         startupinfo)
     PermissionError: [WinError 5] 액세스가 거부되었습니다
     
     During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
     
     Traceback (most recent call last):
       File "D:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 85, in wrapped
         ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
       File "C:/Users/home/PycharmProjects/A~Z azur lane project/music.py", line 67, in 재생
         driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver_dir)
       File "D:\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line
 73, in __init__
         service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
       File "D:\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line
 90, in __init__
         self.service.start()
       File "D:\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 88,
 in start
         os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
     selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'comedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see
 https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

    
    The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
    
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "D:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 939, in invoke
        await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
      File "D:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 863, in invoke
        await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)
      File "D:\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 94, in wrapped
        raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
    discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: WebDriverException: Message: 'comedriver' executable may have wrong permissions. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home
```

plz help me im so stupit so i have no idea...

i re download the chromedriver and that din't work
i have no idea even my code is fine;;;

also my chrome is version 97.0.4692.71 (64bit)
but io can not find 64bit for i used chromedriver_win32.zip

can somebody tell me how to fix

i think i get all correct(i think) but it's not working

[image]

Comment: this thing is hard to ask some quation realy

Comment: `comedriver`???